# Rails noob question: rendering a view with a different layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, view, controller

I did `rails g controller World` and created a new layout also called `world`. I now have `app/views/world/index.html.erb`. This is my `WorldController`:

```
class WorldController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :login_required

  layout "world"

  def show
    #??
  end

end
```

I do not know what to put in my def show so that I can navigate to `localhost:3000/world/index` and have the `views/world/index` page render. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Show refers to the action in the route and not a command to "show it".  Instead you need to define the `index` action.

```
def index
end
```

If this doesn't work.. there is probably a routing problem. Show us config/routes.rb

Comment: OK I added `def index
    @msgs = current_user.all_msgs.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
    @last_msg = current_user.msgs.last
  end
  
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    @msg = @user.all_msgs
  end` but now I get `undefined method 'all_msgs' for nil:NilClass` yet the same def show works in my other views?

Comment: can you show application_controller.rb or wherever current_user and login_required is defined?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is named "World" in the singular.  This typically means your "World" resource is singular.  I.e. there is just one world (not many worlds).  If that's the case, there would be no "index".  You might define the route like this:

```
resource :world

- which would give you the route

/world - mapped to WorldsController#show
```

This assumes the resource is singular, and there is only one world.  So you don't need an id to `#show` it, as it's assumed only one exists (and can be found without an identifier).

If you do want multiple worlds, you'd define your routes with:

```
resources :worlds

- and you'd end up with the routes:

/worlds    - mapping to WorldsController#index
/world/:id - mapping to WorldsController#show
```

I guess the point is, are there multiple worlds?  If there are, then define your routes with `resources :worlds`.  If there is a single world, define your routes with `resource :world`.  In the latter case, there is no index method (as there is a single World, without need of an index)